# How to automate selection and assembly of clips defined in an input file with builtin functions or (python) scripts

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I'm approaching the blender video editor and I'm wondering if there are built-in functions/available (python) scripts to automate the operation of cutting/assembling  subscenes/clips indexed in a file.

Meaning, suppose my director gives me an AVI movie and a file containing a list of times `t_1_in`, `t_1_fin`, `t_2_in`, `t_2_fin`, ... delimiting the subscenes/clips to be cut and assembled.

Is it possible in Blender to automate the cutting and selection of the clips defined by the `t_i`'s in a file (say `.dat`) and their assembly in a continuos sequence?

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on to import EDLs (Edit Decision List), it is a trunk add-on that comes with Blender. As long as your list conforms to the correct source and timecode i don't see why this couldn't work.